# Why do wait and notify function not working properly on same class lock

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Why do wait and notify function not working properly on same class lock?

Please see check below code for wait and notify functionality and its output.

Output:

```
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-2 after notify
```

Expected Result:

```
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-2 after notify
Thread-1 after wait
```

Code:

```
public class WaitAndNotify1 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){            
            @Override
            public void run(){                
                System.out.println("Thread-1");                
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait();
                        System.out.println("Thread-1 after wait");
                    }                    
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){            
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread-2");
                synchronized (this) {
                    notify();
                    System.out.println("Thread-2 after notify");
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you could format your code properly in future...

Answer (score 5):

You're using `this` from an anonymous inner class - so it refers to the instance of that anonymous inner class. There are two different instances (of different anonymous inner classes) so you're calling `wait()` on a different object from the one you're calling `notify()` on.

You don't actually have an instance of `WaitAndNotify1` to synchronize on at the moment. You could move the code to an instance method, then use `WaitAndNotify1.this` to refer to the instance - at which point you'll get your expected output:

```
public class WaitAndNotify1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WaitAndNotify1().test();
    }

    public void test() {
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){            
            @Override
            public void run(){                
                System.out.println("Thread-1");                
                try {
                    synchronized (WaitAndNotify1.this) {
                        WaitAndNotify1.this.wait();
                        System.out.println("Thread-1 after wait");
                    }                    
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){            
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Thread-2");
                synchronized (WaitAndNotify1.this) {
                    WaitAndNotify1.this.notify();
                    System.out.println("Thread-2 after notify");
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```